# Best drop down options for iOS?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

Which is the best drop down options for iPad and iPhone devices?

- **Picker Wheel**
- **Actionsheet**
- Something else?

Comment: Best for what? Best for displaying a list of restaurants in Bolivia? Best for selecting the time your morning alarm goes off? Which one has the best sound effects?

Comment: The difference is based on how many options exist; if it can fit on one screen, use an actionsheet. If it cannot, use a picker wheel. There are other minor considerations, but that is the primary difference between their intended functionality.

Comment: It depends on the context, text length of picked items,  horizontal and/or vetical view, other controls inside the same app (heuristics) and iOS HCI guidelines. Could you tell us a bit more on the above descibed?

Comment: thanks for the comments, for my case i have given the image link, pls check that and suggest

Answer (score 2):

From [iOS Human Interface Guidelines > iOS UI Element Usage Guidelines > Control > Picker](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/UIElementGuidelines/UIElementGuidelines.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH13-SW23):

> **On iPad, present a picker only within a popover**. A picker is not suitable for the main screen.