# How to use picker wheel in ipad

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Best drop down options for iOS?](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/20280/best-drop-down-options-for-ios)

Which is the best **usability method** of using the picker wheel for ipad, **bottom(full view)** or **bottom (middle view)**, **pop up picker view**?

Example:

http://www.hotyogadoctor.com/images/uploads/ipad-names.jpg

http://www.4shared.com/photo/yr77RyJ2/Bottom_Picker_Middle.html

Comment: A closed question can be edited by its author. There's no need to create duplicates.